# Criação de Array dentro de Função

Tags: php, array, switch

Estou a tentar fazer um exercício em que tenho que criar um `array` dentro de uma função, e o mesmo ser acedido através de um código exterior (exemplo: ...php?pais=uk e mostrar Reino Unido - Londres).

Os items do `array` são países e capitais, exemplo: Brasil - br - Brasilia, Reino Unido - uk - Londres, Estados Unidos - us - Washington, etc.

Pontos do exercicio:

- receber um codigo do país, pesquisa-lo no `array` e escrever o nome do país.
- a pesquisa tem que ser efetuada numa função.
- o código do pais tem que ser passado a função como parâmetro.
- a função tem que indicar o pais e a capital.

Fiz anteriormente o exercicio da seguinte forma (com `switch`), mas com um `array` não estou a conseguir, segue o código:

```
function paises($pais){
   switch($pais){
      case 'pt':
         $mensagem = "Portugal";       
         $mensagem2 = "Lisboa"; 
         break;

      case 'br':
         $mensagem = "Brasil";       
         $mensagem2 = "Brasilia"; 
         break;

      case 'it':
         $mensagem = "Italia";       
         $mensagem2 = "Roma"; 
         break;

      case 'uk':
         $mensagem = "Reino Unido";       
         $mensagem2 = "Londres"; 
         break;

      // ......

      default:
         echo "Nenhum país foi escolhido!";

   }         
}
```

Comment: Qual o resultado você espera ter? se possível poste o código na pergunta ao invés de imagens!

Comment: Basicamente estou a fazer alguns exercicios de php, estou a aprender e o exercicio pede o Seguinte:

https://s32.postimg.org/hg1fj72wl/exercicio.jpg

Não consigo postar o codigo, pois nao estou em casa de momento, só a noite! Obrigado! @zekk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Essa é uma alternativa baseada na [solução do @Andrei Coelho.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/142992/15089)  Acredito que mais simplificada.

```
<?php

    function pais($codigo){

        $pais = array(

        "default" => array(false, "Ocorreu um erro"),

        "pt" =>  array("Portugal", "Lisboa"),
        "br" => array("Brasil", "Brasília"),
        "it" => array("Italia", "Roma"),
        //...

        );

       return array_key_exists($codigo, $pais) ? $pais[$codigo] : $pais['default'];

    }

    // Para demonstração:
    // $_GET['pais'] = 'br';


    list($pais, $capital) = pais( $_GET['pais'] );

    // $pais será false se não houver o código!
    if($pais){


      echo $pais;
      echo '>'.$capital;

    }

?>
```

A sua `array` irá conter todos os dados. O `isset()` irá verificar se existe alguma array cujo o índice seja igual ao valor do parâmetro. Existindo o índice `br`, no caso dessa demonstração, ele irá retornar, se não irá retornar o que está definido no `default`.

Comment: Olá Inkeliz, obrigado pela ajuda! Mas se eu quiser que o utilizador abra o browser e escreva o endereço, sendo ele proprio a escolher um codigo como por exemplo " it ", e aparecer pais e capital a que esse indicativo se refere. por exemplo http://localhost/teste.php?pais=it (atraves de arrow_key_exist $_GET?)

Comment: Apenas altere o `isset` para o `array_key_exists`. Para usar o `$_GET['indice']` basta inserir em `pais( $_GET['pais'] )`. Pode ver isto funcionando em http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/896c581e671207002d1f90a8940d592e8eae59eb. Nesse caso apenas altere o valor do `$_GET['pais']` para poder visualizar. Eu realizei as mudanças necessárias, então acredito que está da maneira que deseja.

Comment: Gostei da sua solução @Inkeliz. Mais simplificada realmente.

Answer (score 4):

Uma das formas de retornar um `array` como resultado da função é:

```
function paises($pais){
    $resultado = [];

    switch($pais){
        case 'br':
            $resultado['pais'] = 'Brasil';
            $resultado['capital'] = 'Brasilia';
            break;

        case 'it':
            $resultado['pais'] = 'Italia';
            $resultado['capital'] = 'Roma';
            break;

        // Resto do código...   

        default:
            echo "Nenhum país foi escolhido!";
    }

    return $resultado;
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
$informacoes = paises('br');

if (isset($informacoes)){
    $pais = $informacoes['pais'];
    $capital =  $informacoes['capital'];

    echo $pais . "\n";
    echo $capital . "\n";
}
```

[Ver `demonstração`](https://ideone.com/Xa8MxJ)

Comment: Muito obrigado zekk, eu de momento estou fora de casa, mas logo logo que chegue vou tentar com a sua ajuda e respondo aqui, provavelmente era isso que queria!

Comment: mas assim como fizeste, não acede pela global $_GET pois não? O exercicio tem que ser executado de forma que coloque no url o codigo do pais

Comment: @MarioCaeiro Fiz dessa forma somente para que fosse um exemplo funcional aqui. Tem como usar o `$_get` sim.

Answer (score 3):

Um outro exemplo se precisar:

- receber um codigo do país, pesquisa-lo no array e escrever o nome do país.

  ```
  // abaixo mostra o array que o exercício pede para efetuar a pesquisa
  $paises = array(

     array("br", "Brasil", "Brasília"),
     array("usa", "Estados Unidos", "Washington"),
     array("tur", "Turquia", "istambul")

  );
  ```
- a pesquisa tem que ser efetuada numa função.
- o código do pais tem que ser passado a função como parâmetro.

Estão vamos colocar o array dentro da função e fazer uma pesquisa:

```
    function pesquisa($cod){

    // abaixo mostra o array que o exercício pede para efetuar a pesquisa
    $paises = array(

       array("br", "Brasil", "Brasília"),
       array("usa", "Estados Unidos", "Washington"),
       array("tur", "Turquia", "Istambul")

    );

    //vamos usar este array para retornar os valores
    $valores = array();

    //agora vamos varrer o array e pesquisar o código

    for($x=0; $x < count($paises); $x++){

        if($paises[$x][0] == $cod){

            $valores[0] = $paises[$x][1];
            $valores[1] = $paises[$x][2];

            break;

        } else {

            $valores[0] = false;
            $valores[1] = "Não foi possível realizar sua consulta: código incorreto ou não existe!";

        }

    }

    return $valores;

}

 print_r(pesquisa($_GET['cod']));
```

- a função tem que indicar o pais e a capital.

Quando usamos a url `www.pesquisa.com/index.php?cod=tur`a função retornará:

> Array ( [0] => Turquia [1] => Istambul )